# Get a string inside the 'Value' field from a form using a unique field name

Tags: php, forms

I have a jQuery field which enables my visitors to search for elements. These elements are stored in JSON format and the unique ID's taken from the database are stored as such below (in the 'value' field):

```
<input type="hidden" class="as-values" 
name="as_values_category" id="as-values-category" value="9,11,12,">
```

Obviously, the 3 values shown are if the visitor chooses 3 elements. The user can choose 1-3 elements, resulting in up to 3 results.

The user then goes on and submits the entire page using php. I now need a way to store these 3 variables in the database. How do I 'Get' this data. The 'id' of the form is unique and will always be named 'as-values-category'.

I would then need to go and parse the value to separate the 3 values which I am hoping shouldn't be a problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you submit the form, on the form handler page you can do:

```
$ids = explode(",", $_POST['as_values_category']);
```

After that, `$ids` should be an array containing the elements 9, 11 and 12 (according to your example above).

**Update**

You can iterate through all of the ids with a `foreach` loop, like so:

```
foreach($ids as $k => $v)
    echo($v . "<br>");
```

This should output:

```
9
11
12
```

Comment: Might also want to run that through `array_map('intval', $ids)`.

Comment: Many thanks for this insight, so once I have exploded and split these values accordingly, how can I separate them into 3 variables?

Comment: You shouldn't need to.  Continuing the example, I can access the value of '9' by stating `$ids[0]`, the value 11 by static `$ids[1]` and so on.

Comment: You can just use it as an array, no real need to separate them into 3 variables. If you insist, you can do `list($id1, $id2, $id3) = $ids`, where `$ids` is an array you created using watcher's code.

Comment: Fantastic, works perfectly. Many thanks for taking the time out to help me.

Answer (score 0):

On server side (PHP) you get the value like this:

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST['as_values_category']);
```